# Upgrade sql server 2008 a 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

Donde trabajo estan pensando hacer el upgrade de sql server 2008 (SP4) Enterprise Edition 64 bits A Sql server 2016 ???. tenemos un DWH y me gustaria saber que tengo que saber para la migracion, compactibilidad de versiones entre los dos.

Espero su pronta respuesta.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido este tipo de preguntas son mas para el [chat] porque son de opinión no  hay una respuesta concreta por los diferentes ecenarios que se puedan dar

Comment: @RaulCacacho no es muy de opinión, la verdad. De hecho, esta es la estrategia de recomendación recomendada por Microsoft para migrar de SQL Server 2008 a 2016: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895281.aspx

Answer (score 0):

También debes fijarte las sintaxis que ya no serían válidas en una migración
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016

Por su lado te recomiendo tener un ambiente de pruebas donde puedas habilitar el QueryStore y comparar tus consultas en un nivel de compatibilidad anterior versus 2016. Esto para ver cómo te queda el nuevo estimador de cardinalidad.